# Unable to open a PSD file in gimp

Tags: gimp, psd

[image: error dialogue]

When I try and open this psd file: http://bit.ly/13Y4Ani I get the above error message.  It doesn't mention anything about CMYK or compression modes like most of the other "unable to open questions", and there is no output when running this from the command line. Any ideas?

I'm on Ubuntu 13.04, and using Gimp 2.8.4.  I don't have access to a real Photoshop program to check the file.

Answer (score 0):

I am using GIMP 2.8.4 in Windows 7 and I can't open it either.

I get

[image]

I can open the file in Irfanview and Photshop CS6.

On the Linux side I did observe that I can open the file in Krita, (Fedora 18 using KDE).

Perhaps one of these options help.